# How to use PFQuery to query for exact match to array?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I have a `Game` class in Parse, and one of the attributes is `participants`,  which is an array of `NSStrings` usernames. My goal is to perform a PFQuery based on an NSArray of username (called `selectedParticipants`), so that a Game object is returned if there is an exact match of usernames found `participants`.

However, when I use

```
[queryForGames whereKey:@"participants" equalTo:selectedParticipants];
```

I get an error that I am unable to do a comparison query based on Arrays (`Cannot do a comparison query for type: __NSArrayM`).  I have also tried several other types of query listed in the Parse [reference](http://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html) guide, such as using `whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:`, but they will return extraneous `Game` objects that contains usernames addition to those in `equalTo:selectedParticipants`. Is there a way where I could query by an exact match of arrays using PFQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [iOS Developer Guide on array queries](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-arrays/iOS):

```
[query whereKey:@"participants" containsAllObjectsInArray:selectedParticipants];
```

From what I can tell there does not appear to be a query to match the array exactly with no extra elements, but you can add a statement to check the number of elements in the `selectedParticipants` array against the returned participants.  If they are equal then it is an exact match.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - this is a good idea! While it will return some extraneous objects, the checking locally is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [cloud function](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions) which runs the 'broad' query on the array contents and then filters out any additional items before returning the results. This is the same number of calls from the app and to the data store but more efficient than sending extraneous data back to the app.